# How does typescript has the same level of abstraction as javascript which allows it to qualify for transpiling?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Transpiling is the process of taking source code written in one language and transforming into another language that has a similar level of abstraction. How to identify or what are some specific properties due to which it can be said that typescript transpiles into javscript?

Answer (score 2):

> How to identify or what are some specific properties due to which it can be said that typescript transpiles into javscript?

It's not that it can be said that typescript transpiles into javascript. Most languages can be transpiled into other languages using a transpiler if enough effort were put into it.  Typescript was designed to be a superset of javascript itself with the entire purpose of adding type safety to an otherwise type unsafe language. Therefore the transpilation is an order of magnitude easier than converting between two arbitary languages.

The major and only relevant characteristic is that typescript is a superset of a javascript. I.e. Any javascript is implicitly convertable to typescript without any modification. If Javascript syntax was modelled as a set. That set falls inside the set containing Typescript syntax.

Considering this, the only change needed to convert Typescript into javascript is to remove some of that extra syntax. In practice, things are a bit more complicated as Typescript has added some constructs that simplify coding but may not work directly in javascript. There's also complexities introduced by the varying levels of javascript features that different browsers support. Typescript is highly configurable for these scenarios and perform transformations to product output code suitable for the target environment.

The best option is to try it for yourself here and see the transpilation in action. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

As for abstraction, typescript does not really add any abstract features, it only adds abstract type specifications. Compare this to a object oriented language such as C# which supports polymorphism, inheritance, encapsulation where abstraction is integral to resolving dependencies and dispatching method calls, typescript does not add any of that, it merely adds a bunch of types, in fact typescript is not even a programming language per se, it does not have it's own run time environment, it cannot be run till it's converted to Javascript. I don't see abstraction being relevant here. Javascript is a dynamic language where type resolution and dispatch is performed at run time. Abstract constructs do not exist, only concrete types.

Comment: So can we say typescript compiles to javascript? Thanks for the explanation above.